# Как сконфигурировать правила ESLint для отдельного проекта VS2017 без установки Node.js?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, eslint

В студии есть настройка, включая которую можно юзать ESLint сразу, из коробки. Однако в таком случае будет использоваться глобальный конфиг.

Как настроить студию на работу с другим ESLint-конфигом, не используя при этом Node.js? Или как расшарить глобальный конфиг на всю команду и добавить его в VCS?

Comment: А расширение угадать надо? Вроде почти везде используется локальный файл, если он есть. И в чём проблема установить nodejs?

Comment: Вы разве не в курсе, что нода давно уже ставится вместе со студией? Правда, не последней версии.

Comment: @Qwertiy не понял вопрос про расширение. Не нашёл информации как установить локальный конфиг, кроме как через консоль ноды, а по умолчанию используется глобальный

Comment: @PavelMayorov я подозревал, поскольку eslint как-то же надо работать, но это не отменяет вопроса. Я впервые сталкиваюсь с необходимостью подключения eslint, поэтому многие вопросы для меня не ясны

Comment: @Anatol, локальный конфиг это обычный файл со специальным именем и json внутри. Его и руками создать можно.

Comment: @Grundy это я уже понял, вчера перенёс глобальный конфиг в директорию проекта, вроде работает. Непонятно только почему при наличии ошибок (в соответствии с конфигом) нормально проходит билд. Как настроить ошибки билда?

Comment: А как билд собирается? Кажется, нужно добавить проверку непосредственно в билд и в случае ошибки билд будет падать

Comment: @ThisMan должно из коробки работать, насколько я знаю, без костылей, если стоят галочки нужные. Они вроде стоят, но может быть не все... Какое ваше предложение?